# XMLReader skips particular row

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sax

this is my method

```
private void ParseXML()
{
    int pubid = 1;

    settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
    using (reader = XmlReader.Create(FileName, settings))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.IsStartElement())
            {
                switch (reader.Name.Trim().ToLower())
                {

                    case "book":
                        book = new Book();
                        book.Pubid = pubid;
                        book.Pubtype = "book";
                        book.Pubkey = reader.GetAttribute("key");
                        ParseBook(reader, book);
                        pubid++;
                        break;

                    case "article":
                        article = new Article();
                        article.Pubid = pubid;
                        article.Pubkey = reader.GetAttribute("key");
                        article.Pubtype = "article";
                        ParseArticle(reader, article);
                        pubid++;
                        break;

                    case "incollection":
                        incollection = new Incollection();
                        incollection.Pubid = pubid;
                        incollection.Pubkey = reader.GetAttribute("key");
                        ParseIncollection(reader, incollection);
                        pubid++;
                        break;

                    case "inproceedings":
                        inproceeding = new Inproceedings();
                        inproceeding.Pubid = pubid;
                        inproceeding.Pubtype = "inproceeding";
                        inproceeding.Pubkey = reader.GetAttribute("key");
                        ParseInproceedings(reader, inproceeding);
                        pubid++;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am parsing this file. http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/

However, i have checked the xml with other parsers and it seems the incollections element is in the xml.

However, when i run this piece of code, my case "incollection" is not fired. Others works fine.

This is the xml file which is 1.2Gb.

Debugging does not even hit the in collection = new incollection so there is no error

Comment: Please improve this: 1. Include a sufficient quote of the XML (the link has three XML files, two of which are too large for a quick look). 2. What does debugging show?

Comment: That's a little better, but far far better to have information inline in the question (along with completed, ie. compilable) code that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox reports this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity

Location: http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/dblp.xml
Line Number 26, Column 37:
<journal>technical Report 248, ETH Z&uuml;rich, Dept. of Computer Science</journal>
------------------------------------^
```

The error character is ü

```
&uuml;
```

Perhaps you should consider using CDATA which allows ampersands...

```
 <![CDATA[
   This is some text with ampersands & other funny characters. >>
 ]]>
```

EDIT: Have a read of this document [reading-xml-with-an-into-c-sharp-xmldocument-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121511/reading-xml-with-an-into-c-sharp-xmldocument-object)