# Calling method from catch method doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, xml, exception

I'm trying to call a method from a catch block but the xmlnode inside the method doesn't seem to work. I'm getting a null. If I call the same method from the try block it works.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();

try
{

 doc.Load(f.FullPath);
// do some work 

}

 catch (Exception e)
 {
  if (e is XMLException)
  {
   checkXML(ref doc);
  }

public void checkXML(ref XmlDocument doc)
            {

                XmlNode xn = doc.SelectSingleNode("/BroadcastMonitor/Current");
                xn["name1"].InnerText = SecurityElement.Escape(xn["name1"].InnerText);
                xn["name2"].InnerText = SecurityElement.Escape(xn["name2"].InnerText); ;


            }
```

Now when the catch block calls method 'checkXML', i get xn as null. But if I execute the same from the 'try' block just to check, 'xn' has a value. 'doc' too has a value regardless of when called try or from catch block.

Why is this happening? Please help me understand.

**EDIT**

```
<BroadcastMonitor>
<updated>2014-10-17T07:56:30</updated>
<Name>TESTING</Name>
<Current>

    <artistName>اصاله&  نصرى</artistName>
    <albumName>شخصيه عنيده</albumName>
    <CategoryName>ARABIC & SONGS</CategoryName>

</Current>
</BroadcastMonitor>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program and go step-by-step through your code to see what the content of the `doc` variable is in the exception code block?

Comment: yes I have done that, and as mentioned in my question. doc variable has value

Comment: Does your code fails (=exception is raised) at `doc.Load(...)` or at `do some work`?

Comment: Try your code with a minimal XML structure. If it still does not work (so the problem is probably not an incorrect xml), please paste also the xml code in your question too.

Comment: @pasty: okay found the problem when it tries to load and there is a escape entity or something it would give me an xmlException, in that case the load is not complete and the elements are missing. thanks for the pointer.+1 for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml contains an **&** character which is not a 'valid' xml character and must be escaped.

```
<CategoryName>ARABIC & SONGS</CategoryName>
```

So it's causing your `Load()` method to throw the exception.

What you should do is escape all the invalid characters in your xml string before passing them on to an xml parser like so

```
yourXmlString = XmlConvert.EncodeName(yourXmlString);
```

You can then pass the yourXmlString on to the parser like so

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString);
```

or if you don't want to or can't use the `XDocument` class you will need to make sure you save the xml encoded so that the `Load()` method of the `XmlDocument` class will be reading a file that is properly encoded.

Note that `XmlDocument` and `XDocument` classes are not the same thing and have some significant differences. Method `Parse()`, if I remember correctly, is one of the advantages that `XDocument` has over `XmlDocument`.

**EDIT :**

You can read the xml file into a string using the File class

```
var yourXmlString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

Comment: Hey Alex, +1 for a detailed description. You solution looks good. But how do I get my xmlfile into yourxmlstring, using a streamreader or something.

Answer (score 0):

XmlDocument is a reference type... no need to pass it with ref.

And my guess is that its failing to load in the first place so doc is really null

Comment: yes it's null, trying to figure out a way at the moment how to read the xml and fix the escape characters. Do you have any clue on this

Comment: can you paste in an example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this document is missing its xml declaration tag.

try:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument;
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(f.FullPath))
{
    doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: The xml declaration is there, it's just that I haven't added it here. The error is in <CategoryName>, look at the & sign. This is illegal in XML. I just want to read the whole xml and fix the escaped entities.

Comment: Well i would approach it with fixing the writing of these documents (to valid xml). otherwise you would need something like regex replacing and that is some task...

Comment: this is document is being writen by a software, I approached the support for the software, and they said this software is quite old and they will not spend time in fixing it's bugs anymore. So for me the only deed left is to fix it myself programmatically

Comment: any clues on Regex would be much appreciated

Comment: Its not that hard... i just need some time to figure it out.. we just need to find all inner node values an call html.encode on em... im currently not on my computer though

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.IO.File.ReadAllText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx) to get all text from file into a string variable :

```
string invalidXml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(f.FullPath);
```

For this *particular* XML, you can simply replace `&` with it's encoded version `&amp;` to make a valid XML string :

```
string validXml = invalidXml.Replace("&", "&amp;");
doc.LoadXml(validXml);
.....
```

Related question for reference : [Reading XML with an "&" into C# XMLDocument Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121511/reading-xml-with-an-into-c-sharp-xmldocument-object)

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution:

```
    private static Regex InnerValues = new Regex(@"(?<=<(.*?>)).*?(?=</\1)",RegexOptions.Compiled);

    private static XmlDocument LoadInvalidDocument(string path)
    {
        XmlDocument result = new XmlDocument();
        string content = File.ReadAllText(path);

        var matches = InnerValues.Matches(content);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            content = content.Replace(match.Value,  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(match.Value));
        }
        result.LoadXml(content);
        return result;
    }
```